# How to dynamically change the background color of an Appbar and a button with a button?

Tags: flutter, function, android-studio, colors, appbar

I would like to change the color of an AppBar, text, and button with a button and its onPressed function.

I would like the color to update when tapping/pressing the button.

The colors of AppBar, text, and button would be different for each one.

Answer (score 0):

Create two variables to store the color value.

```
Color _appBarColor = Colors.blue , _textColor=Colors.white;
```

Change the value of the variables on button pressed

```
onTap:(){
_appBarColor = Colors.grey;
_textColor = Colors.white;
setState((){}); //-> To Change the state of the screen
}
```

Comment: Any changes to state should occur in the setState callback.

Comment: Do I have to put something into the setState(() {}) ?

Comment: not necessarily to put something inside setState((){}).

You just need a stateful class instead of stateless.